# Constantly Checking Collisions and OnTriggerEnter

Tags: collision-detection

Ok so i wanted to ask a basic question.
suppose i have an edge collider 2d,

Fact - if i add the OnTriggerEnter() into my code. it will check for trigger enters constantly.

Now, 
If the edge collider exists but i don't put OnTriggerEnter(), will the game still check for trigger enter collisions? or will it not check for them?

Answer (score 1):

The physics system is always checking for collisions. `OnTriggerEnter` is there to receive events when a collision does happen, and that collision involves a trigger. If you're attempting to optimize, you should remove the collider. Removing the endpoint for the events is an optimization, but that's mostly from not having to run the code contained in the `OnTriggerEnter` event handler.

In other words, Unity's checking for collisions will not increase or decrease based on `OnTriggerEnter`.

Comment: thanks! Just one more thing, is it better to use an edge collider or using 5 raycasts everytime i want to check for collision?

Comment: A collider will be more efficient